# Get JSON Value from Key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, undefined

Why is **undefined** getting logged?

```
var arr = [{"eat" : 0}, {"sleep" : 1}, {"code" : 2}];
var key = "eat";
console.log(arr[key]);
```

I expect to see `0` in the log.

http://jsfiddle.net/jFFW5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I don't see any JSON here. I see a plain JavaScript array object - JSON is a data serialization format.

Second, you're probably looking for `arr[0]` which would return `{"eat": 0}`.

Arrays are used for storing *sequential* data.

Alternatively, you can store them in an object if that fits what you actually wanted:

```
var arr = {"eat" : 0,"sleep" : 1,"code" : 2};
var key = "eat";
console.log(arr[key]);
```

---

<sup>Note: in more modern implementations - you should probably use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of an array for that. Or use `Object.create(null)`</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You've got an array with three properties. Their names are "0", "1", and "2". Those names are derived implicitly from the fact that three values (three object literals) are listed in the array literal.

In order to find an entry in the array with a property "eat", you'll have to iterate through the array.

Answer (score 2):

It's not JSON, it's an array of single item JSON objects.

You could get 0 like this:

```
console.log(arr[0][key]);
```

But it would be better to have an actual JSON object that you could use in the way you want. That would look something like `{"eat" : 0, "sleep" : 1, "code" : 2}` (just remove the `[]`s and internal `{}`s. If you do this your `arr[key]` will work as expected... although `arr` might not be the best name for a JSON object :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertThatArrayToAnObject(arrayOfObjects) {
  var returnObject = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
    var key = Object.keys(arrayOfObjects[i])[0]
    returnObject[key] = arrayOfObjects[i][key] 
  }
  return returnObject
}
```

Comment: some explanation, please!